# Mongo regex for "not match" or inverse

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-negation

My mongo documents all contain a field called `templateName`. There are a few documents that contain the value: `a_SystemDefaultTemplate`, `b_SystemDefaultTemplate`, `c_SystemDefaultTemplate` etc.

I would like to `find` those documents whose templateName does not end with (or contain) `SystemDefaultTemplate`

I know it can be done using the `$not` operator like so:

```
db.collection.find({templateName: {$not: /.*SystemDefaultTemplate$/}})
```

But how do I do the same using regex?

I have tried the below but it does not seem to work.

```
db.collection.find({templateName: {$regex: "^(.*SystemDefaultTemplate$)"}})
```

Comment: You can also just combine `$not` and `$regex`... `{$not: {$regex: "^(.*SystemDefaultTemplate$)"}}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try with negative look ahead ( meaning it should not contain the mentioned phrase)

```
db.collection.find({templateName: {$regex: "^(?!SystemDefaultTemplate$)"}})
```

`?!` is negative look ahead. And here is some explanation about it from http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds

"Negative Lookahead After the Match: \d+(?!\d| dollars)
Sample Match: 100 in 100 pesos
Explanation: \d+ matches 100, then the negative lookahead (?!\d| dollars) asserts that at that position in the string, what immediately follows is neither a digit nor the characters " dollars"

Negative Lookahead Before the Match: (?!\d+ dollars)\d+
Sample Match: 100 in 100 pesos
Explanation: The negative lookahead (?!\d+ dollars) asserts that at the current position in the string, what follows is not digits then the characters " dollars". If the assertion succeeds, the engine matches the digits with \d+."

Comment: UPDATE 2023:


The $not operator can perform logical NOT operation on both:

    Regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/)

    For example:

    db.inventory.find( { item: { $not: /^p.*/ } } )

$regex operator expressions

For example:

db.inventory.find( { item: { $not: { $regex: "^p.*" } } } )
db.inventory.find( { item: { $not: { $regex: /^p.*/ } } } )

Comment: It doesn't look to be working as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sv9PyyZBT2l
I guess you meant `^(?!.*SystemDefaultTemplate$)` (including the `.*` inside)