# mongodb: regex with multiple excluded phrases

Tags: regex, mongodb

I wish to find all the items that match some field - but in addition, exclude from the results those items that match *multiple*  regular expressions. what's the syntax here?

in other words: find X and (not regex y) and (not regex z) etc.

a similar question with a single phrase and some additional data can be found here: [Mongo regex for "not match" or inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940340/mongo-regex-for-not-match-or-inverse)

Answer (score 1):

One way, using a single regex pattern:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({fieldName: {$regex: "^(?!Y|Z$)X$"}})
```

The regex pattern says to match:

```regex
^             from the start of the field
    (?!Y|Z$)  do not see patterns Y or Z
    X         match pattern X
$             end of the field
```

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({$and: [{"fieldname":"some-value-I-want"},{"fieldname":{$not: /some-regex-I-dont-want-1/}} , {"fieldname":{$not: /some-regex-I-dont-want-2/}}]})
```